# Add a table before innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Tags: html

I'm calling a table from a remote server like this

```
document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

but I'm wondering if I want to add a title on top of this table how is that coded? I'm thinking of adding a table and putting that title in

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title of the Table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `<th>` html element.

Comment: inside a `<thead>` element

Comment: Is the table coded after `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){` in here `<table><th>...</th></table>` , then `document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`? Sorry I'm a little slow.

Answer (score 0):

If JQuery is an option, it becomes very easy:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#datatable').prepend('<thead><tr><th>Title</th></tr></thead>');
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Will try it when the server's up and report back. Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: I'm using the `ready()` option in the example but since this looks to be part of an ajax call you would perform the `prepend` call after a successful return, when you know you have a good datatable.

Comment: Good to hear. Glad to help.